# How to appendRow (or write data more generally) to Google Sheets from a custom function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api, google-directions-api

I've written a custom function [=ROUTEPLAN(origin,destination,mode,departuretime)] in the Google Sheets script editor. The function assigns a unique ID to the request, calls the Google Maps Directions API, passes as params the arguments as listed in the function, parses the JSON and extracts the duration, end latitude and end longitude for each step of the journey, and then appends a row for each step, with the request ID for the whole journey, the sequential step number, the duration, end latitude and end longitude:

```
function ROUTEPLAN() {

  //Call the google route planner api
  //(variables for api declared here but removed for brevity)
  var routeResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=" + origin 
                                        + "&destination=" + destination 
                                        + "&mode=" + mode + 
                                        "&region=uk&departure-time=" + departuretime 
                                        + "&key=MYAPIKEY")

  //Assign a unique ID to this request
  var requestID = Date.now() + Math.random();

  //Parse JSON from routeResponse
  var json = routeResponse.getContentText();
  var data = JSON.parse(json);

  //Insert the RequestID, step number, duration, end Latitude and end Longitude for each step of the journey into the RouteDetails sheet
  var steps = data["routes"][0]["legs"][0]["steps"];
  for (i = 0; i < steps.length; i++) {
    var stepID = i + 1;
    var duration = steps[i]["duration"]["value"];
    var endLat = steps[i]["end_location"]["lat"];
    var endLng = steps[i]["end_location"]["lng"];
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("RouteDetails")
    sheet.appendRow([requestID,stepID,duration,endLat,endLng]);                                                                                                                   
  }
}
```

Or at least that's what I want it to do. It worked fine until I tinkered with it, and now I'm getting an ERROR when I call the function in the spreadsheet, telling me I don't have permission to call appendRow. I know why this is happening (although I don't understand why it wasn't happening before), but I cannot work out what I'm supposed to do about it.

If appendRow exists, there must be some circumstance in which it can be used to write data the sheet, but I can't figure out the circumstances in which permission to write to the sheet would be granted.

The purpose of the sheet is to provide data to a chatbot (the chatbot app has read & write permissions to the sheet). I'm not intending to provide access beyond that (i.e. i'm not intending to publish this for wider use). I've tried going down the installable trigger route, but despite following all the instructions that made absolutely no difference to the outcome. From the limited understanding I gained from reading about API Executables, that doesn't seem to be an option either.

Can anyone tell me how to solve this? Thank you :-)

Comment: Without seeing your code, `appendRow()` is a `Sheet` method, meaning you need to modify the sheet itself, not the data in the sheet. Post some relevant code and you're more likely to get an answer.

Answer (score 3):

A custom function can not modify the structure of the spreadsheet, so calling `appendRow()` is not allowed as stated in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions):

> A custom function cannot affect cells other than those it returns a value to. In other words, a custom function cannot edit arbitrary cells, only the cells it is called from and their adjacent cells. To edit arbitrary cells, use a custom menu to run a function instead

If you want to return multiple rows from your function, it needs to return a two dimensional array. Note however that custom functions have the same limitation as native functions of not being able to overwrite content i.e. if you try to return two rows but the row below is already filled the function will error out.